# Change controller id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want a piece of code on the index of my Code Igniter's script so I can change the identety or name of my controller from agent69 to agent007_and_supergirl,and also a way to beat any rule that pages might have against using underscore to separate words as an amendment.

In other words I want that all the calls that the processor of my server has inside my code igniter for agent69 be translated to calls to agent007_and_supergirl

Is just a change of identety for the controller without altering the main controler's functionality and without getting my hands dirty with coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want re route your default controller url, you have to edit routing configuration like this:

in application/config/route.php

```
$route['agent007_and_supergirl'] = 'agent69';
```

Now agent69 Controller will be accessible by `http://youriste.com/agent69` and `http://yoursite.com/agent007_and_supergirl` as well

[CodeIgniter URI Routing Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Well hope that you can help me master this code that goes on the index of my code igniter script

<?PHP header("($customControllerName): $this->agent69 = ['agent007_and_supergirl']"); exit ?>

Comment: Please if you have another question, check this answer and ask an another question. I will see it.

Answer (score 0):

Working on config/routes.php yelded miserabe results on past,remember that is an identity matter

And I want all the calls of agent69 be sent to agent007_and_supergirl that is its new identity

What was successfull on the past about this mattar was controller and file cloning,it worked masterfully
but this only intercepted few server calls so for me to get all the server calls, I need to clone every
single fie on the script so I feel silly teling you again thats why I didnt want to get my hands dirty with code
because is plenty of code.
Well hope that you can help me master this code that goes on the index of my code igniter script--///The code cant appear here so its below in the comment to lighta thanks 4 readin

Comment: Please also do help me perfect this other little piece of code:

$config[‘controller_customName’,‘agent69’] = ‘agent007_and_supergirl’,TRUE;